# Фильтрация при выводе терминов таксономии в форме создания ноды

Tags: php, drupal

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой - существуют "устаревшие" термины таксономии, ими уже пользоваться не будут, но так как они использовались ранее - удалять их тоже не хочется. Появилась идея установки флага на "устаревшие" термины. Подскажите пожалуйста (или скажите где копать) как исключить "помеченные" флагом термины из списка, который выводится при создании ноды.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/103583/30399

1. Установить модуль [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference).
2. Создать представление (view) терминов с типом Entity Referance, настроить в нем необходимые фильтры или условия.
3. Создать поле типа Entity Reference
4. В настройка поля выбрать taget type: Taxonomy Term.
5. Выбрать 'Views Filter by an entity reference view'. В качестве 'View used to select entities' указать представление, созданное в шаге 2.